# Как передать массив, объявленный через typedef, в качестве аргумента функции?

Tags: const, typedef, указатели, ссылки, c++

Имеем:

```
typedef float M[16];
```

Хотим перемножить две матрицы src1 и src 2 и поместить результат в dest

Варианты передачи параметров:

```
//Вариант 1. Прямая передача. Паршивый вариант, просит много памяти.
 void M_MM_Multiply(M dest,M src1, M src2);

//Вариант 2. Через указатель. В коде образуется много операций разыменования.
 void M_MM_Multiply(M* dest,M* src1, M* src2);

//Вариант 3. Через ссылку.
 void M_MM_Multiply(M& dest,M& src1,M& src2 );

//Вариант 4. Через ссылку с const.
 void M_M_Multiply(M& dest,M& const src1,M& const src2);
```

Какие еще варианты я упустил и какой самый лучший с точки зрения производительности и кошерности?

Comment: Ну начнём с того, что вариант 1 -- просто не рабочий. Параметры передаются по значению, и первый параметр dest по выходе будет иметь то же значение, что и перед вызовом.

Comment: @alexlz, почему же не работающий. Такая фигня

    typedef float M[4];
    void xx (M res, M a1, M a2){
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       res[i] = a1[i]+a2[i];
    }
    main () {
       M x = {1.1, 2, 3, 4},    y = {10, 20, 30, 40}, res;
       xx(res,x,y);
       for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(M)/sizeof(x[0]); i++)
          cout << res[i] << '\n';
    }

выводит

    c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ ./a
    11.1
    22
    33
    44
    c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ 

Другой вопрос, **зачем такое вообще нужно?**

Comment: Значит придётся читать (хотя и неохота) о передаче массивов в качестве параметров. gdb даёт

    (gdb) p &x
    $1 = (M *) 0xbffff34c
    (gdb) p a1
    $2 = (float *) 0xbffff34c

совсем выскоуровневый язык, блин. Но замечание @igumnov о запросах массы памяти тут несправедливо.

Comment: @alexlz, конечно  замечание @igumnov о запросах массы памяти тут несправедливо.

Более того, (IMHO) попытки использования вещей типа typedef и чего-либо отличного от указателей и традиционной записи массивов до определенного уровня владения языком и понимания функционирования компьютера на уровне "абстрактных" команд и ячеек памяти (а также организации виртуальной памяти) ни к чему хорошему не приведет.

Ученик должен "собаку съесть" на адресной арифметике с разными типами данных и их размещении в памяти (в т.ч. при передаче как параметров функции, так и получении результатов из нее).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поскольку речь идёт о массиве, между ссылкой и указателем технически нет никакой разницы. Код на выходе будет одинаковый. Традиционно ссылка используется в связке с модификатором const, а указатель - без него.

Для большей кошерности можно использовать указатель и отдельным параметром передавать размер. Тогда функция будет более универсальной и сможет работать с матрицами разного размера.

Но если нужен только один размер, то более кошерным будет вариант с константными ссылками.

Однако подлинным шедевром был бы вариант, которого у вас нет: шаблонная функция для любого размера, принимающая константные ссылки и в качестве бонуса возвращающая константную же ссылку на результат.

```
template <size_t N>
const float (&mul(const float (&s1)[N], const float (&s2)[N], float (&dest)[N]))[N];
```

Comment: Нужен только один размер, но вариант с шаблонной функции просто выше всяких похвал, спасибо! Вот исходник всей библиотЭки http://www.gamedev.ru/files/?id=81073.